# Response.Redirect to another page from ajaxtoolkit tabpanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a question about redirecting from a TabPanel Control.
I have a AjaxToolkit's TabPanel. 
In the code behind I generate ImageButtons. When user clicks on imagebutton, I want to redirect him to another page in my web-application.
When this is outside of the Panel, it works correctly. But inside of tabcontainer it does not works.

Here the two methods what I've done:

```
public void BilderDarstellen()
        {
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Bilder_Hochgeladen/"));
            string[] Bildernamen = getFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Bilder_Hochgeladen/"),"*.jpg|*.png",SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var bild in di.GetFiles())
            {
                HtmlGenericControl createDiv = new HtmlGenericControl("DIV");
                //createDiv.ID = "createDIV";
                createDiv.Attributes.Add("class", "createDiv");          

                #region IMAGEBUTTON bauen "myImgBut"
                ImageButton myImgBut = new ImageButton();
                string pfad = Server.MapPath("~/Bilder_Hochgeladen/" + bild);
                myImgBut.ImageUrl = GenerateThumb_URL(pfad); //"data:image/png;base64," + base64String; ;//"~/Bilder_Hochgeladen/" + bild;
                myImgBut.ToolTip = bild.ToString();
                myImgBut.ID = bild.ToString();                                        
                myImgBut.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(myImgButtonClick);
                #endregion

                createDiv.Controls.Add(myImgBut);

                #region BUTTON nauen "bButton"
                Button bButton = new Button();
                bButton.ID = bild.ToString() + "l";
                bButton.Text = bild.ToString() + " Löschen";
                #endregion
                //Panel1.Controls.Add(bButton);
                //Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
                createDiv.Controls.Add(bButton);

                Panel1.Controls.Add(createDiv);
                i = i + 1;                
            }
        }               

        private void myImgButtonClick(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            ImageButton src = (ImageButton)sender;
            Response.Write("Click auf " + src.ID);            
            Response.Redirect("~/BildShow.aspx?ID=" + src.ID);            
        }
```

Help me please.

Greetings
Kai

Comment: Your way is too complicated. Instead, you may use *HyperLink* control and give it CSS class to make a look like an imagebutton.

Comment: Let's think that you're gonna to use ImageButton. Okay, it is good. What how far have you tried to test? Have you tried to debug your code, to set breakpoints and see all your values of *bild*, *pfad*, so on

Comment: Morning, i have tried debugging, breakpoints and so on. Your idea with Hyperlinkcontrols is super. This is perfect. And its running now. Why the Response.redirect not Running i cant declear. The Site is running wonderfull but an click to imagebutton ... nothing appear. So what ... Hyperlink will work. Thank you Khazratbek.

Comment: You are welcome. Next time, if you can't reach something, try to look for an another way to do that ;)